# How to receive the notification action using WorkManager

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

Before the introduction of `WorkManager`, I was using an `IntentService` for my notification actions. So If I had several actions, I would simply pass those actions in the intent and then receive them like this in my `IntentService` class.

```
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    assert intent != null;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    NotificationTasks.executeTask(this, action);
}
```

However, I am trying to do the same thing for the `WorkManager` and I am stuck. I have seen this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#params but it does not actually help because all I get are inputs and not the passed intent string action. 
Help please, thanks.

Comment: can you add some code you used??

Comment: @NehaRathore, the code I used initially with the Firebase JobDispatcher is above. I need to know the equivalent of this line  `String action = intent.getAction();` in the WorkManager

Comment: I guess you have to set action

Comment: That is exactly what I have done in my notification `PendingIntent`. Now how do I get that action from the  `WorkManager`

Answer (score 0):

WorkManager does not have the notion of Intents since it needs to serialize its input data at the app level.  So you have two ways of doing this:

1. You can make an input Data that has all the individual pieces of your Intent, and then reconstruct the Intent in your worker.
2. You can continue to use IntentService.  Is there a particular reason you're using WorkManager in this case?

Comment: According to the documentation here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb  `FirebaseJobDispatcher` is no longer recommended. I think I will try to use a `BroadcastReceiver` and see what happens

Comment: `JobIntentService` is a valid alternative.  Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService

Comment: Fyi, the JobIntentService class has been deprecated.